# String url-encoded twice, I can't get the initial string

Tags: java, string, urlencode, urldecode

I have to encode a URL a string that is already partially encoded. When I encode the string, it encodes twice the characters that were already encoded. After decoding, I can not return to the string because it has been encoded twice.

Any way to encode only the unencrypted characters?

```
urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
```

Example url to be encoded:

```
http://gastro-huc.org.pt/index.php?view=article&catid=41%3Ateses-de-mestrado&id=41%3Ateses-de-mestrado&format=pdf&option=com_content&Itemid=68
```

Comment: What's the original?

Comment: What part of the example is encoded ?

Comment: @Tibus 41%3Ateses, is %3 url encoding or not?

Comment: @shmosel the string before being encoded.

Comment: Which is......?

Comment: Oh, yes, `%3A` is `:`, I've missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

decode it first and then encode it

```
String id = "http://gastro-huc.org.pt/index.php?view=article&catid=41%3Ateses-de-mestrado&id=41%3Ateses-de-mestrado&format=pdf&option=com_content&Itemid=68";
id = URLDecoder.decode(id);
String urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
```